# Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality. #Android Studio not found at /path/to/android/studio

Tags: android, flutter

[facing problem to setup android studio for a flutter. (Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality). I already installed flutter plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I38jR.png)

[I have installed a couple of time.][2]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I38jR.png)

Answer (score 0):

after viewing the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/I38jR.png
I think your paths are not set correctly.
For this, you should run the command

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir <path of your android studio directoy>
```

here <path of your directory looks something like this

```
/usr/local/android-studio
```

or maybe something else depending on the way you have installed android studio.
Similarly, for android studio SDK you can run

```
flutter config --android-sdk <path of your Android sdk directoy>
```

P.S.
Most probably the next error you might face is the plugins. So after configuring the paths rerun flutter doctor. That error can be solved by installing the plugins in android studio.